# Bounty questions not ordered by size properly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty, new-nav

Looking at bounty questions, on [page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=bounties&sort=size&page=2&pageSize=30) the bounty is +250 but on [page 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=bounties&sort=size&page=14&pageSize=30) (last but one) the bounty is at +500. This does not meet my expectation of sorting.

Proof screenshots:

[image: Screenhot of page 2]

[image: Screenshot of page 14]

---

Update 2015-10-28 (with new navigation)

[image: NewNav Bounties by size, page 2]

[image: NewNav Bounties by size, page 29]

Comment: Cross site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263828/what-is-the-bounty-size-sort-actually-sorting-by-in-new-nav

Comment: @Andy: nice finding, but no answer there as well...

Comment: It is fixed now on my home PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed for me as of 2015-12-22.

Page 2:

[image: Page 2]

Page 25:

[image: Page 25]

Answer (score -1):

Can you update the bug if it's still present in this release?

Comment: I have added updated screenshots of the new navigation. Still the same issue. (Should this have been a comment instead of an answer?)

Comment: I've updated the [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263828/what-is-the-bounty-size-sort-actually-sorting-by-in-new-nav?noredirect=1#comment870594_263828) post showing that the bug is still present.